# MetadataType for Complex Objects

Tags: c#, inheritance, model-view-controller, metadatatype

I have some complex objects. Let's suppose my objects are as follows:

```
public class addressModel
{
    public string street {get;set;}
    public string number {get;set;}
    public string state {get;set;}
}

public class contactModel
{ 
    public string firstName {get;set;}
    public string lastName {get;set;}
    public addressModel address {get;set;} 
}
```

Now I need additional classes that inherit from contactModel, but one of them requires addressModel and the other does not. This is easily handled by adding the [Required] attribute to a MetadataType class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(driverMetadata))]
public class driverModel : contactModel
{
        
}

public class driverMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public addressModel address {get;set;} 
}
```

But what if I need a third class that only needs the street and number properties of the addressModel to be required? Would I need to create a new class that inherits from addressModel and assign the MetadataType to this new class?

I totally understand that I could create a new address model class with only those 2 properties, but now imagine a class with several tens of properties. We do not want to create ad-hoc classes that mix and match the different properties we need.

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up on this and proceeded with the ad-hoc classes. This greatly reduces reusability (and therefore productivity), but as we say in Chile: "the optimum is an enemy of the good".

Comment: I think the ad-hoc classes are the way to go anyway.  You can end up with complex, fragile hierarchies - base models that get more or do more than you really want in your derived models - and once you've stepped into that mess, it's hard to get out.